# Check if mouse cursor changed to a hand while hovering over a link in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way for me to detect if the mouse pointer changes to the finger/hand pointer while using Selenium in Java?

Comment: I think I have understood your question but I was wondering what can be a valid usecase/business-case. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can wait for the css value of the pointer to change.

```
// depends on which element you want to wait, here take <body> as an example
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).GetCssValue("cursor") == "pointer");
```

Original Post: [Selenium: How can I wait until the cursor changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789402/selenium-how-can-i-wait-until-the-cursor-changes)

Comment: so instead of wait, would I use "pointer"?
based on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087975/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-a-hand-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-list-item

Comment: Thanks vor the solution! But in java, == returns wrong value.     public boolean hasFingerCursor(WebElement rowElement){
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(rowElement).perform();
        return "pointer".equals(rowElement.getCssValue("cursor"));
    }